# Information of a sentence

Tags: logic, philosophy-of-mathematics

Someone rolls a six-sided die, but before he rolls it he says, "the outcome can be 1 or 2."

Is he lying because he didn’t refer the other possible outcomes?

Comment: whether he is a liar is subject to opinion...

Comment: This could be a logic question; see Rus's answer for a useful way a formal translation of your person's statement can help clarify what they're saying.  But it's not clear from your question that what you were looking for was logical clarity!

Answer (score 3):

Formally speaking, he is not even wrong.

- There is a six-sided dice where each side represent a number from 1 to 6.
- The statement is: "The outcome can be 1 or 2."
- If he is wrong then outcomes 1 and 2 are impossble.
- They are possible, thus he is right.

The statement would be false if he said "The outcome can *only* be 1 or 2." Would it be lying even in this case? Well, being wrong does not mean lie. Lying implies that the liar himself does not believe in his own words. The person who is wrong because of unawareness or unintended errors (fallacies, acceptance of wrong premises, etc.) is not lying.

According to [Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/lie) 'lie' is:

> say or write something that is not true in order to deceive someone

So, there is an important word "deceive". If the speaker intentionally, in order to deceive people, says "The outcome can *only* be 1 or 2." he is lying. Because:

a) The statement is wrong.

b) It is made in order to deceive people.

Comment: thanks for the answer i just wanted to know that not saying all the possible outcome isnt wrong..sorry for saying lying misconception.

Comment: It can be expressed as quantified formula. I prefer to see it as quantified formulas, where typically quantifiers are: ∀ (all ... are ...), ∃ (some ... are ...) and ∃! (only one ... is ...). There also is counting quantifier. Then the first formula is ∃x: (x = 1) ∨ (x = 2). It is valid formula assuming standart dice.